# What options are available to copy date output to a variable?

Tags: variable, assignment

Context: router outfitted with Merlin AsusWRT.  The goal is to append the epoch time to a text file from the UNIX command-line within router. Example:

```
{date:1532348491}
```

The date command return Unix Epoch Time

```
date +%s
```

Is there a clever one-liner command that can append the Epoch time?

Attempts to assign the output to a variable were not successful, from the UNIX command line:

```
myVariable = date +%s
```

Comment: In what language? Do you want the output of `date +%s` or `date +'{date:%s}'` stored in a variable? Where does the _text file_ come into play?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  Thanks for the good questions: I have updated the OP.   A UNIX .sh script records data in a text file and the goal is to append the Epoch time to each measurement record (not discussed in OP).  If it is not necessary to save the date to a variable to append it to the text file, that's fine

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
myVariable=`date +%s`
```

or preferably:

```
myVariable=$(date +%s)
```

the one-liner: {`date +%s`} returned {1532368565}.
the one-liner: {$(date +%s)} returned {1532368565}.

One-liner that appends to a data file:

```
echo {`date +%s`} >> myDataFile.txt
echo {$(date +%s)} >> myDataFile.txt
```

Comment: it will be worth if we wanted to use nested variables  $(echo $(foo)).